# Making Clean URLs in this situation

Tags: url-rewriting

this question is really hard to search as I don't even know what keywords to use, altho ive tried but i still cant find the answer.

I have a database driven website: www.abc.com and every page will look like this

```
 www.abc.com/?page=somepage
 www.abc.com/?page=another_page
 www.abc.com/?page=yet_another_page
```

I use index.php to read the value of "?page" and then load the required page according to the value of "?page"

since "?page" is common how can i simplify my urls to look like

```
www.abc.com/somepage 
www.abc.com/another_page
www.abc.com/yet_another_page
```

Thanks

***EDITED***

On further thinking, I want to be a bit more specific about it... the problem is...

How to make it in a way that when an address like **www.abc.com/somepage** is typed in to the address bar, it should process that address as if it was  **www.abc.com/?page=somepage** and not go direct to **/somepage** as if it was a folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
 # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Code from the drupal .htaccess (I replaced q by page)